# How to hide the dock on one desktop but make it visible in others?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I have 3 desktops with different apps and windows on.

I want to set the dock to auto-hide in one of these but keep it visible in others.

How can I achieve this?

If I choose auto-hide, it becomes so in all desktops.